# Jasper Report keeps printing the same report multiple times in the excel file

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

My Jasper Report runs the query and obtains the data perfectly fine. The data is displayed in a table component and exported to an excel file.

My problem is, the table component, which contains the data, is printed multiple times (approximately 20 times). I do not know why this is happening.

I am relatively new to Jasper Reports (I've been learning it for a week) so I could very well be missing something.

The following is the jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="projectbycustomerreport" pageWidth="752" pageHeight="572" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="476a09b7-7823-4320-aaa0-3721aee471cc">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="94"/>
<subDataset name="TableDataset" uuid="09d8857b-956c-490e-b34d-72860983bdf9">
    <parameter name="DATE_FROM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="DATE_TO" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="MAIN_CUST_NUM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="MAIN_PROJ_NUM" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT TSDATE, TSCONO, TSCSNO, TSDEPT, TSPRNO, TSPHAS, TSMSNO, TSTASK, ITEM, TSSRNO, TSPSAN, TSWONO, TSSIRN, TSTSKH, TSBILH, TSNBHC, TSNBHI, TSTRFH, TSOTHH, TSTRVT, TSMILE, TSCCNM FROM WeeklyTimesheetTable WHERE((TSDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(date,$P{DATE_FROM}) AND CONVERT(date,$P{DATE_TO})) AND (TSCSNO=$P{MAIN_CUST_NUM}) AND (TSPRNO=$P{MAIN_PROJ_NUM}))]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="TSDATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSCONO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="TSCSNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSDEPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSPRNO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="TSPHAS" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="TSMSNO" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSTASK" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="ITEM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSSRNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSPSAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSWONO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSSIRN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TSTSKH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSBILH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSNBHC" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSNBHI" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSTRFH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSOTHH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSTRVT" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSMILE" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="TSCCNM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="TSCONO"/>
    <sortField name="TSDATE"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="CUST_ID" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="PROJ_ID" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="DATE_FROM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="DATE_TO" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="DATE_GEN" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="TIME_GEN" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="MAIN_PROJ_NUM" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="MAIN_CUST_NUM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT TSDATE, TSCONO, TSCSNO, TSDEPT, TSPRNO, TSPHAS, TSMSNO, TSTASK, ITEM, TSSRNO, TSPSAN, TSWONO, TSSIRN, TSTSKH, TSBILH, TSNBHC, TSNBHI, TSTRFH, TSOTHH, TSTRVT, TSMILE, TSCCNM FROM WeeklyTimesheetTable WHERE((TSDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(date,$P{DATE_FROM}) AND CONVERT(date,$P{DATE_TO})) AND (TSCSNO=$P{MAIN_CUST_NUM}) AND (TSPRNO=$P{MAIN_PROJ_NUM}))]]>
</queryString>
<field name="TSDATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSCONO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="TSCSNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSDEPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSPRNO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="TSPHAS" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="TSMSNO" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSTASK" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="ITEM" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSSRNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSPSAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSWONO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSSIRN" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TSTSKH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSBILH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSNBHC" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSNBHI" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSTRFH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSOTHH" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSTRVT" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSMILE" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TSCCNM" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="191" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="a64247fb-c0f0-4ed8-9d4b-d086199fdee5" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="752" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="70fc51ae-580a-4a3d-961e-db5a2f8f6991" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="752" height="32" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project By Customer Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="79506db1-e406-4f92-9014-775900b6bba8" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="36" width="752" height="140" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6e97c9f7-360a-4476-bdc0-2f68f2c4aa17" x="0" y="5" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer ID & Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="43f905dc-3c9d-42f3-96fd-089b46678c8d" x="0" y="32" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project ID & Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0f6002cb-b314-44c3-8d3b-979512fd0bac" x="0" y="60" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Period:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5699709c-40df-44d4-9c27-df1f48de225b" x="0" y="88" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date Generated:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c53d2360-f096-41b2-990e-27beb8608b4b" x="0" y="116" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Time Generated:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="02cf4c1b-53e4-46e9-80bd-9513012ad35e" x="150" y="5" width="602" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{CUST_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ad104c49-6300-4897-b2bc-7147bdab5bca" x="150" y="32" width="602" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{PROJ_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c56252dc-3713-4d49-99a8-df6a3ea056a0" x="150" y="88" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_GEN}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="cdf7af05-739a-4086-8d38-9fb3e0f45b35" x="150" y="116" width="226" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TIME_GEN}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="94b1054e-ff88-4b6b-ac53-5e9caa4ed0a3" x="150" y="60" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_FROM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="238f5e67-19f3-40c4-a9c2-b2ec1bbcbd32" x="250" y="60" width="26" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[to]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c119a6d7-b873-4d2e-bdbf-4482454b67d6" x="276" y="60" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_TO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="572" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="0f51d841-bb5b-4775-9b87-03ba695a6971" key="table 2" style="mainTable" x="0" y="0" width="752" height="572"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset" uuid="7d17fcfc-0541-4e5e-9a72-86649e38cd06">
                    <datasetParameter name="DATE_FROM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_FROM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="DATE_TO">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_TO}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="MAIN_CUST_NUM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MAIN_CUST_NUM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="MAIN_PROJ_NUM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MAIN_PROJ_NUM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="d375f5a3-db9e-450d-8ac2-e1a9a6fc18fc">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="4cd206f2-6591-41a5-969c-9466034aac24" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSDATE]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="47c0d3dd-aac2-44ff-a3e5-426cd092fd54" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="587ce56a-9008-43be-b850-dc5397b81c3a">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="73460bc8-c487-4712-8a50-99f624a6bab5" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSCONO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="ce6aaaad-562e-4e8f-9841-d51759e57035" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSCONO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="83d4280b-05a0-425e-a49c-f7eccc1880bf">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="834e3ec6-bdb8-46f5-99e5-9953a615f382" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSCSNO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="584eadf1-ab41-44b6-9453-1c2fe27f329c" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSCSNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="076aa9f0-5519-4c17-a0d0-43263458e17f">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="2cbbc5b0-a585-4ee2-8f48-a7c336ca090e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSDEPT]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="fdf84ff5-50b9-4ec8-b849-0bf4de80a7a7" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSDEPT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="bc1af644-0380-4abe-bc32-8e130d24ffdf">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="3c0ebe11-a46a-421c-b312-99022544ca2a" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSPRNO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="6e028901-0e32-4467-9387-79eefb3d54fc" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSPRNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="6ba32984-eeba-4b3c-815d-1c041a04bb08">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="7d6f0145-27c8-4f23-9e05-8a2c3714dfc7" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSPHAS]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="757f479d-f624-403f-94b2-a1a7f5deff21" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSPHAS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="91e6bf63-edaf-4795-8e86-74a1b0c36e82">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="9687b2b4-4c0d-4771-96e5-906481ec8bae" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSMSNO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="1efbda7d-3eb4-4f9e-9e01-04932ce2c518" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSMSNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="a5280cec-20f6-4f6b-978e-e6b9c8791e9a">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="3d4e6cac-734d-4944-9723-f5ecdd9cff8e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSTASK]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="10c3896f-7c7a-443f-ae9a-fb6834d930a6" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSTASK}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="2780dc1e-fec7-4366-b97d-2bed6556b8ab">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="955b38e6-caf2-4952-9601-97fd88f61a9d" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[ITEM]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="e97694ca-dae7-40df-9b53-8aeeb138e546" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ITEM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="02111dc5-db46-4f99-a7c6-b26723cc1847">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="2615591e-7a96-47cf-9ca0-be9a563bf1b4" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSSRNO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="694bcb7f-f283-4b62-a6ff-649fe4ab72c2" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSSRNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="52fc695f-50db-4bea-aef7-ad2cd7c9f108">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="eacf6552-ac9e-4450-9f15-7a237c6cfec8" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSPSAN]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="3a61da59-d709-4776-b805-e3b261f76786" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSPSAN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="af9ce744-f683-4a3e-a75a-0ce9e58ab288">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="09e9bafe-84b1-4837-9fff-e028570c2aba" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSWONO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="6cde712a-24db-4099-b602-7f05b87f38ad" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSWONO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="a2c49ac5-3f2a-4bd3-a4d8-30efd4163beb">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="5d992a75-c66e-49ce-9f2a-09769ac751c1" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSSIRN]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="2dd04d7f-6477-45f7-b013-568d3ad0db26" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSSIRN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="3484cb89-dd95-49eb-8c85-afc7567ed5bc">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="7bdbb4e4-8fb8-4706-9fc2-5f5b85aac79e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSTSKH]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="09ec98f7-b2e4-438a-9a8d-7dd51db70cba" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSTSKH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="ad93e1c3-e4ac-4367-a31e-440eddf776cd">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="3446f9bd-a05b-4574-a9a8-0f59ebdfed4e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSBILH]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="cbcab416-75b2-4706-bfb1-d34ff6323b18" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSBILH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="1b4fdc9d-5c59-4443-a7c8-6e5edd51ad75">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="d57feffc-245b-4bc7-85e4-38e8396c837e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSNBHC]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="89731118-1073-48e3-a321-76a316c28b55" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSNBHC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="93186b6f-adb3-4861-a503-4e782bf837b2">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="bbefa769-4e52-4f96-bb54-c4d019651d8b" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSNBHI]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="a257d745-f999-4826-b210-b60b7a871343" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSNBHI}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="89f3dea3-c95e-4099-bf3c-b1998a04b08c">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="4c405fd9-1210-40fd-9ca4-c298f81d842b" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSTRFH]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="bf152421-b30e-46c0-aec5-59330e8c39d6" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSTRFH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="f1584ffe-d3a0-4716-9fd8-8304fb4e612d">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="ee774f5c-e8b1-4c41-8df3-912b68f88970" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSOTHH]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="5324f7a9-8001-4537-b239-a3763aeda84e" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSOTHH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="e66738ed-9531-446b-a628-412161414eda">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="37b96194-8dde-4a13-a2c9-1ed2a78c8f51" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSTRVT]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="a4b7814a-ae7b-4b7b-adca-eac9bbe9abec" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSTRVT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="58ce548b-0fc0-4ca7-901f-4aa76fd24a6e">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="9e7d4717-6a96-44cc-940a-7821b306713a" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSMILE]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="e4124f5e-8538-4243-8a35-204e515d02e9" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSMILE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="7e7203e2-0707-4c7a-9e8e-f3a568387a20">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="082ae041-bbd5-42c3-bedd-2efd715bbe54" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSCCNM]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="a4e5d07e-c19c-4760-a0fd-415830172292" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSCCNM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And the following is code is my testing Java Program that I am using to practice:

```
public class JasperReporter {

private Connection sqlConnection;
private JasperReport report;
private JasperPrint printer;
private JRXlsExporter exporter;

public JasperReporter() {
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource ds = new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setDatabaseName("TimesheetControlSystem");
    ds.setServerName("192.168.0.88");
    ds.setPortNumber(1433);
    ds.setPassword("*****");
    ds.setUser("tester");
    try {
        if ((this.sqlConnection = ds.getConnection()) == null) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed.", "Connection Status", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (SQLServerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JasperReporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void createReport() {
    try {
        this.report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("F:\\Local Documents\\Programming Projects\\Java\\Testing Projects\\JasperReporter\\projectbycustomerreport.jrxml");
        HashMap param = new HashMap();
        param.put("PROJ_ID", "9000: Internal");
        param.put("CUST_ID", "9055097252: Test");

        param.put("DATE_FROM", "2013-01-01");
        param.put("DATE_TO", "2013-01-28");

        param.put("DATE_GEN", "2013-01-30");
        param.put("TIME_GEN", "1:28 PM");

        param.put("MAIN_CUST_NUM", "1036066254");
        param.put("MAIN_PROJ_NUM", new Integer(9000));

        this.printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, param, this.sqlConnection);

        this.exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        this.exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, this.printer);
        this.exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, new File("F:\\Local Documents\\Programming Projects\\Java\\Testing Projects\\JasperReporter\\jasperxls.xls"));
        this.exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        this.exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
        this.exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        this.exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JasperReporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    jasperreporter.JasperReporter jr = new jasperreporter.JasperReporter();
    jr.createReport();
}
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I could not include this in the question due to 30000 character limit. The Java program also prints out the following error, multiple times when generating and exporting the excel file:
     Jan 31, 2013 11:02:40 AM  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.GenericElementHandlerEnviroment  loadBundles
     WARNING: Found two generic element handler bundles for  namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports

Comment: i think the error message is unrelated. You might want to open a separate question. If I use your JRXML in iReport 5.0 I cannot reproduce this error message.

Comment: I guess should also note that I am using iReport 5.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the table component in the detail band, whereby you also have a main report query. The detail band gets rendered as often as there are rows in the result set for the main report query. Move the table in the summary band of the report, then it will be only rendered once.

```
<summary>
    <band height="138">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="0f51d841-bb5b-4775-9b87-03ba695a6971" key="table 2" x="0" y="0" width="752" height="138"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset" uuid="7d17fcfc-0541-4e5e-9a72-86649e38cd06">
                    <datasetParameter name="DATE_FROM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_FROM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="DATE_TO">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATE_TO}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="MAIN_CUST_NUM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MAIN_CUST_NUM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <datasetParameter name="MAIN_PROJ_NUM">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MAIN_PROJ_NUM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="d375f5a3-db9e-450d-8ac2-e1a9a6fc18fc">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="4cd206f2-6591-41a5-969c-9466034aac24" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSDATE]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="47c0d3dd-aac2-44ff-a3e5-426cd092fd54" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="587ce56a-9008-43be-b850-dc5397b81c3a">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="73460bc8-c487-4712-8a50-99f624a6bab5" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <text><![CDATA[TSCONO]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="ce6aaaad-562e-4e8f-9841-d51759e57035" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TSCONO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: I moved the table to the summary band. It somewhat worked. The table was generated once, as you said it would be, but there was no data in the table, only the column headings appeared.

Comment: hm.. i tried it with a simplified dataset. I copy the summary band into the original answer. After I moved the table I verified the configuration of the table dataset, it seemed all right, and I get data shown.

Comment: One of things I noticed in your example, is the in the definition for detailCell and columnHeader, you have another field called "rowSpan". Would this affect the output in anyway?

Comment: I apologize, the fault is on my end. When I posted the Java program, I had made a modification to the primary key that would be used to obtain the data. I have changed it back to what it should be and the data is obtained successfully and printed once. Thank you very much

Comment: I would like to give this answer a +1, unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to do so. I apologize about that. Thank you again for your help MrsTang.

Comment: > The detail band gets rendered as often as there are rows in the result set for the main report query

Is there any specific reason for that? I was getting nuts until i found this comment here! tyvm